# Telerik PdfViewer - Binding to a PDF source

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, telerik

I've tried the samples on telerik's website as well, and to no avail.  So I have this code:

```
    public ICommand EmailPopUpCmd { get; set; }
    private void EmailPopUp(object sender) {
        //ToDo: pdf viewer pop up
        selectedDataRow = (DataRow)sender;
        var window = new Window();
        window.Content = new EmailView() { DataContext = this}; //shares the same data context
        MemoryStream str = new MemoryStream();//= new MemoryStream(pdfAsByteArray);//new System.Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/Resources/TestPDF.pdf", System.UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
        using(FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(@"C:\Source\UI.MailViewer\Resources\TestPDF.pdf")) {
            str.SetLength(fs.Length);
            fs.Read(str.GetBuffer(),0, (int)fs.Length);
        }
        AttachmentPath = new PdfDocumentSource(str);

        if (window.ShowDialog() == true) {
            //from child back to parent
        }
    }
```

> C:\Source\UI.MailViewer\Resources\TestPDF.pdf
>   Is where my PDF is located and I bind it to the UI as follow:

```
telerik:RadPdfViewer x:Name="pdfEmailViewer"
                          Grid.Row="2"
                          DocumentSource="{Binding AttachmentPath,Converter={StaticResource DebugConverter}}">
```

Now using this, I get an object not set to an instance error.  Any idea as to why? Using the debug converter, the value of the PDF document created is null, why is that happening?

Comment: Creating a window in your ViewModel isn't MVVM.  You should be doing this in your codebehind.

Comment: I am aware of that, I would like to sort out the above mentioned problem before cleaning and sorting the code itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so to help other users, I found this on the telerik forums: ([Telerik Forum Link](http://www.telerik.com/forums/documentsource-strange-problem))

There is one additional thing to do in order to make RadPdfViewer work in a WinForms application: you should ensure that the Application.Current property is initialized before the user control is initialized, for example by adding this code in the constructor of the user control:

```
public PdfViewerControl()  {  
if (Application.Current == null)    
    new Application();   
InitializeComponent();  
}
```

This worked for me in WPF as well.